# Как заменить стрелочную функцию обычной?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Помогите пожалуйста заменить стрелочную функцию обычной

Есть такой сервис:

```
export var HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" },
  { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" },
  { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" },
  { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" },
  { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" },
  { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" }
];

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes() {
      return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }   
}
```

Так он работает:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { }

    heroes: Hero[];
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    selectedHero: Hero; 

    onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }

    getHeroes() {
          this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }   
}
```

А так не работает:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { }

    heroes: Hero[];
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    selectedHero: Hero; 

    onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }

    getHeroes() {
          this._heroService.getHeroes().then( function(heroes) {
                this.heroes = heroes;
          });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты забыл `return` и ссылку на себя ?

```
getHeroes() {
    let self = this;
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then( function(heroes) {
        return self.heroes = heroes;
    });
}
```

Comment: ты еще про  this забыл

Comment: @Grundy та пофик)